# What is the meaning of local inertia conjugation property?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, galois-theory

In *Hatcher, Allen; Lochak, Pierre; Schneps, Leila*, [**On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.028), J. Reine Angew. Math. 521, 1-24 (2000). [ZBL0953.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20030)., we have:

> *Abstract*. Let $\widehat{G T}^{1}$ be the subgroup of the Grothendieck-Teichmüller group having $\lambda$-component equal to 1 . We define a subgroup $\Lambda$ of $\widehat{G T^{1}}$ by adding one additional defining relation to the definition of $\widehat{G T}^{1}$, and show that $\Lambda$ acts on the tower of profinite mapping class groups $\hat{\Gamma}_{g, n}^{m}$ for all $g, n, m \geqq 0$, respecting all the natural arrows $\hat{\Gamma}_{g^{\prime}, n^{\prime}}^{m^{\prime}} \rightarrow \hat{\Gamma}_{g, n}^{m}$ coming from cutting out a topological surface of genus $g^{\prime}$ with $n^{\prime}$ punctures and $m^{\prime}$ boundary components inside one of genus $g$ with $n$ punctures and $m$ boundary components. The proof that these homomorphisms are respected is an easy consequence of a certain local inertia ***conjugation*** property of the action of $\Lambda$.

What is the meaning of **local inertia** ***conjugation*** **property** in this paper? What is the meaning of ***conjugation***?

Comment: Have you read the paper?  Presumably the answer to your question is there.

Comment: @RyanBudney . Yes but I can't find.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I did a search through the text.  "Inertia" is mentioned in the abstract, then never again.  "Conjugation" is mentioned 6 times total, all in one cluster pgs. 19--20, without any hints as to what "local inertia" might mean.  I think Hatcher logs into MO every once and a while.  Likely he will see your question.  I am unaware if the other authors frequent this forum.

Comment: @RyanBudney . I sent email to prof.hatcher . He said me : You will have to ask one of the other authors of the paper since your question involves parts of the paper I did not write and do not know much about, unfortunately.

Comment: Lochak has a paper that describes the usage of "inertia": https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.lochak/textes/garside.pdf